# what's the exactly meaning of EV_TIMEOUT in libevent?

Tags: timeout, epoll, libevent

In [Programming with Libevent](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/) book, it says:

> ```
> EV_TIMEOUT
> ```
>
> This flag indicates an event that becomes active after a timeout
>   elapses.

AFAIK, an event associate with socket fd will become active when network IO event is ready, which is notified by select/epoll/poll/kqueue.

If `EV_TIMEOUT` make an event active, while the socket fd is not ready, will event_base do the callback ?

Or the socket fd is ready, while `EV_TIMEOUT` is not, will event_base do the callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I understand.

```
void (*event_callback_fn)(evutil_socket_t, short, void *);
```

The `short` flag will tell callback what happened exactly.

When timeout, `short & EV_TIMEOUT == true`, when socket is ready, `short & (EV_READ | EV_WRITE) == true`.